# Android data binding on android 4.1 doesn't work

Tags: android, data-binding, binding, android-databinding

https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/index.html:

> The Data Binding Library offers both flexibility and broad
>   compatibility — it's a support library, so you can use it with all
>   Android platform versions back to Android 2.1 (API level 7+).

But when I'm trying to use data binding in my project it just doesn't work, there's no reaction for that, TextViews are empty, onClick bindings just desn't workx, please help me I need support for android 4.1, google tells that it should to be possible even for 2.1, I don't think they're lying :/

Example code:

```
<FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="130dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="15"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:background="@color/colorSecondary"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:onClick="@{ () -> view.save() }" <!-- binding -->
            android:layout_margin="15dp">
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/save"
                android:textAllCaps="true"
                android:textColor="@color/colorForeground"/>
</FrameLayout>
```

Code behind:

```
public void save()
{
    if(viewModel.car.save() != 0) //If you put breakpoint here it won't be hit
        getLayoutRoot().goBack();
}
```

Code works fine on API level 19+

Comment: Is it working with other API levels?

Comment: Kindly post the code that you have tried so far.

Comment: Yes, totally on 19+ API level works just fine.

Comment: try using AppcompatTextView

Comment: @Harsh It's in the question now, that is example code that doesn't work for me.

Comment: @Harsh It doesn't work with any kind of fields I can't even set visibility with databinding

Comment: I am moving at the moment. Will try to help you once I get back. Meanwhile I think using support widgets shall your problem.

Comment: Me too, I'll update complete xml and java files later.

Comment: please create a bug report with a sample project that reproduces your issue.

Comment: Thank you for your interest, that was my oversight (returning false on PreBind event)

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem, I was returning false on PreBind event when SDK_INT < KITKAT in my automatic transitions function:

```
        binding.addOnRebindCallback(new OnRebindCallback()
        {
            @Override
            public boolean onPreBind(ViewDataBinding binding)
            {
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
                    return false; //should be true, that's it

                ViewGroup sceneRoot = (ViewGroup) binding.getRoot();

                TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition(sceneRoot, transition);

                return true;
            }
        });
```